# Looping rows with MySQL relationship tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have three tables:

**Door**

`ID | Name | Price | etc.`

**Panel**

`ID | Name`

**Door-Relationship**

`door_id | panel_id`

I would like to generate an HTML/PHP table with one row for each door that shows the panel related to it:

**Door List**

`Name | Price | Panel | etc.`

I'm having trouble writing the MySQL query for this. How should I go about in requesting this info from the database? Thanks!

What I tried:

```
<?php   
$catalog_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM door");


$panel_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT door.name as door, panel_profile.name as panel FROM door_relationship
INNER JOIN door
    ON door_relationship.doorid = door.door_id
INNER JOIN panel_profile 
    ON door_relationship.panel_id = panel_profile.panel_id
INNER JOIN door");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($catalog_query) and $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($panel_query))
{
echo    '<tr>
            <td>' . $row['door'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['sqft_price'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['door_price'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row2['panel'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['joint'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['collection'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['min_sqft'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['min_width'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['min_height'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['max_width'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['max_height'] . '</td>
        </tr>'
        ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Paste the SQL you are trying

Answer (score 1):

This might help (not tested):

```
SELECT
  door.id AS door_id,
  door.name AS door_name,
  door.price AS door_price,
  door.etc AS door_etc,
  panel.id AS panel_id,
  panel.name AS panel_name
FROM door, panel
INNER JOIN door_relationship
  ON door_relationship.door_id = door_id
  AND door_relationship.panel_id = panel_id
```

Comment: How will this get the panel name if the panel table is not called?

Answer (score 1):

query must be :

```
select d.name doorName, p.name panelName, otherFields from Door d, Panel p, Door-Relationship r where p.id = r.panel_id and d.id = r.door_id group by d.id order by d.id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.Name, d.Price, p.Name, etc

FROM Door d, Panel p, Door-Relationship DR

WHERE d.id = dr.door_id and p.id = dr.panel_id;
```

Comment: Please don't use old-style syntax, use ANSI join syntax.